# How to POST login requests using ureq?

Tags: rest, post, rust, ureq

I made a small prototype for my program in Python, in which I need to log in to a website. For doing that I did:

```py
import requests as req

session = req.Session()
req.post("somesite.com", data={"procedure": "login", "username": "JohnSmith", "password": "hunter7"})
```

And all of my API calls later worked well.

However, in Rust (using ureq), I can't seem to accomplish that. This is my code:

```rust
let agent = ureq::Agent::new();
agent.post("somesite.com")
      .query("procedure", "login")
      .query("username", "JohnSmith")
      .query("password", "hunter7")
      .call().unwrap();
```

I have checked and in the Rust version there isn't any session cookie, unlike in the Python version.

Comment: I forgot to specify in the post, I *did* enable the "cookies" feature of ureq in my Cargo.toml.

Comment: The `query()` method seems to be for URL query parameters, meanwhile in Python version you are presumably sending the payload via POST body. Have you tried [send_form](https://docs.rs/ureq/2.3.0/ureq/struct.Request.html#method.send_form)?

Comment: @justinas Thank you very much! I didn't even see that method on docs.rs, and I thought I had to do it with URL parameters since Firefox's DevTools showed the request using a ?key=val&otherkey=val format.

Answer (score 1):

As @justinas said, I needed to use `Request::send_form` instead of `query`.